# Free WPF Flow charting Component

Tags: wpf, user-interface, components, flowchart

I am looking for a WPF Flow charting component.  Something that will let you draw boxes and display lines between them based on some object structure/collection.

Anyone know about anything like that out there?  I prefer free as this is an open source project I plan to put it in.

Answer (score 6):

The [WPF Diagram Designer on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDiagramDesigner_Part4.aspx) does much of this.